# codeigniter , mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm new to CI and I'm having a problem with MySQL

**Table1**

```
id | house_id | 
1  |  1       | 
2  |  4       | 
3  |  3       |
```

**Table2**

```
house_id | image_name | 
4        |  a.jpg     | 
4        |  b.jpg     | 
3        |  c.jpg     |
```

How I can select (distinctively) `image_name` for each `house_id` by using CodeIgniter Active Record class?

Comment: Hehe Kemal, you beat me to it. @datta, please do not mark up your questions with HTML. StackOverflow uses Markdown. Use the provided toolbar to markup your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html
this is the API you are looking for `$this->db->distinct();`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple method group_by in codeigniter model

```
function get_house_image(){
$items = $this->db->select('house_id', 'image_name')
->from("table1")
->join("table2", "table1.house_id = table2.house_id")
->group_by("table1.house_id")  
->get();    
return $items->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model

```
function get_house_image($id){
$this->db->where('house_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('table2');
return $query->result();
}

In your cotroller
function house($id){
$data['house'] = $this->your_model->get_house_image($id);
$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

In your view foreach the result and use it. This gets the house's picture which id you pass in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join of tables to get records as follow:

```
$this->read->select('t1.house_id,t2.image_name');
 $this->read->join('table2 as t2','t1.house_id = t2.house_id','left');
 $result = $this->read->get('table1 as t1');
if($result){
      $data = $result->result_array();
      print_r($data);
}
```